# submit a POST request with parameters and a body using Java & REST

Tags: java, rest, servlets, post, httprequest

I'm trying to use an existing API that calls for a json object to be "submitted" using POST, but the page also requires a few parameters in request, for this example we will use name, and email. I'm super new to REST so I'm probably making an ignorant mistake somewhere here.

Here is the code I have so far in my servlet:

```
String path = "http://www.test.com/submit";
URL url = new URL(path);
conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

Gson gson = new Gson();

//julySchedule is the object I want to submit with this request alongside the parameters.
String input = gson.toJson(julySchedule);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("HTTP POST Request Failed with Error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
```

I've tried to put the parameters in the URL, like:

```
/submit?name=Name&email=test@gmail.com
```

But that didn't work, because POST requests wont accept parameters like that.
Then I tried to add it to the Output stream like:

```
String params = "name=Name&email=test@gmail.com"
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(path.toBytes());
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();
```

But that didn't work either. Am I making a really dumb mistake somewhere?

Comment: I've learned that, and that's why I tried the code below it. Is there a better way to pass "parameters" in a POST request?

Comment: Post request can be get by getInputStream()/getReader() in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine for a POST request to contain query string(Though not best practice).

Since you use `application/json` as `Content-Type`, I assume your payload has to be a JSON object. You cannot mix your params in POST body. You have 2 options:

1. Kep email&name in QueryString, and json in POST payload: What you did should work.
2. Use POST payload only: Set `Content-Type:` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as follows: `name=NAME&email=EMAIL&jsonPayLoad={Your Json Object}`. Server should extract `jsonPayLoad` from POST payload.

Make sure to escape using `encodeURIComponent` before writing to POST output stream.

Comment: I've tried both of these, but I am getting an error 400 when I submit this.